# Get the unique array from an array with the lowest number

Tags: php, arrays

im having trouble figuring this one out, the scenario is, that there is an multidimensional array, in which there is name, id, and number in an array, what i want is to get the unique array in which array having same name should not appear, this can be done and i had done it, but i also want that the array that is returned should contain the lowest num, i hope this would help make you understand
i have

```
Array(
[0]=>array(
    [id]=>1
    [name]=>abc
    [num]=>4)

[1]=>
array(
    [id]=>2
    [name]=>efg
    [num]=>4)

[2]=>array(
    [id]=>3
    [name]=>abc
    [num]=>2)
)
```

Now its a rough array representation, what i want from this is

```
Array(
[0]=>array(
    [id]=>3
    [name]=>abc
    [num]=>2)

[1]=>
array(
    [id]=>2
    [name]=>efg
    [num]=>4)
```

What im using:

code.php

```
<?php 
$details = array( 
0 => array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mike",    "num"=>"9876543210"), 
1 => array("id"=>"2", "name"=>"Carissa", "num"=>"08548596258"), 
2 => array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mathew",  "num"=>"784581254"), 
); 

function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    $key_array = array(); 

    foreach($array as $val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
        $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
        $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
    } 
        $i++; 
} 
return $temp_array; 
} 
$details = unique_multidim_array($details,'name'); 
?>
```

This function returns me

```
Array(
[0]=>array(
    [id]=>1
    [name]=>abc
    [num]=4)

[1]=>
array(
    [id]=>2
    [name]=>efg
    [num]=>4)
```

Comment: you never do a "is this current element smaller than a previous one" comparison. you're just looping over the array and storing the last-found key.

Comment: @mastermind, where does `$details` array come from? it doesn't have the same `name` keys

Comment: @MarcB yeah i know that and i said it in my answer also that i cant seem to figure this out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce`:

```
$result = array_reduce
(
    $array,
    function( $carry, $item )
    {
        if( !isset( $carry[$item['name']] ) || $item['num'] < $carry[$item['name']]['num'] )
        {
            $carry[$item['name']] = $item;
        }
        return $carry;
    },
    []  // This parameter (empty array) is optional in this case
);
$result = array_values( $result );
```

We compare each array element with constructing returned array (initially empty): if in returned array doesn't exists an item with key = `$item['name']`, we add it; otherwise, if current item has `num` value lower than corresponding returned array item, we replace this item with current item. At the end, we use `array_values` to remove associative keys.

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => abc
            [num] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => efg
            [num] => 4
        )

)
```

---

- Read more about [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)
- Read more about [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with two loops

First, group the values by name, then number

```
foreach ($your_array as $value) {
    $names[$value['name']][$value['num']] = $value;
}
```

Then iterate the result of that, sort name by key (num) and append the first element to the final result.

```
foreach ($names as $set_of_nums) {
    ksort($set_of_nums);
    $result[] = reset($set_of_nums);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have considered the below example.

```
$details = array( 
0 => array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mike",    "num"=>"123"), 
1 => array("id"=>"2", "name"=>"Carissa", "num"=>"235"), 
2 => array("id"=>"3", "name"=>"Mike",  "num"=>"5"), 
3 => array("id"=>"4", "name"=>"Tom",    "num"=>"256"), 
4 => array("id"=>"5", "name"=>"Tom", "num"=>"500"), 
5 => array("id"=>"6", "name"=>"Mike",  "num"=>"7"), 
); 

function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    $key_array = array(); 

    foreach($array as $k=>$val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
            // storing the array with the key
            $key_array[$k] = $val[$key]; 
            $temp_array[$k] = $val; 
        } else{
            foreach($key_array as $r=>$p){
               //check for the array with the name
                if($temp_array[$r]['name'] == $val['name']){ 
                    // compare the value
                    if($temp_array[$r]['num']>$val['num']){ 
                        // store the new array to the temp_array with same key of key_array 
                        $temp_array[$r] = $val; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    return $temp_array; 
} 
$details = unique_multidim_array($details,'name');
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Mike
        [num] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Carissa
        [num] => 235
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Tom
        [num] => 256
    )
```

)

You can sort the output array using any of the sort functions as you desire.